# How to fix Circular dependencies in React, with custom 3rd parties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, rollup

I built a custom npm package that exports the main component from my project.

That main component contains also a 3rd part libs.

When I execute `yarn build` inside of the package, the result is that I get a warning: `Circular dependencies`

The interesting part is when I run `build` inside of the project where that component lives, I am not getting `Circular dependencies`.

That errors appear only when I run build as part of the package, and I am using ROLLUP to bundle the package.

Around 50 - `Circular dependencies`.

> node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/answer.js ->
> node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/question-common.js
> -> node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/answer.js node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/answer.js ->
> node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/question-common.js
> -> /Users/nikolatrajkovic/Desktop/enrollment-client/src/node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/answer.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/@bestowinc/enroll-sdk-core/build/lib/answer.js utils/logger.ts -> utils/metadata/index.ts ->
> utils/metadata/segmentIdentifyHelper.ts -> utils/logger.ts ...and 41
> more

I have no idea why this is happening, just want to understand why :)

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: `utils/logger.ts -> utils/metadata/index.ts -> utils/metadata/segmentIdentifyHelper.ts -> utils/logger.ts` that looks like a legit cycle: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#cycles

Comment: The way to solve cycles is generally by adding a third module to prevent the circle dependency.